# Change filtered value in controller

Tags: angular

I have to change the value of a filtered value in Angular. It's working fine doing the filter thing but now I need to change the text on condition.

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
   {{ vm.currSugNeches | SugNechesRcsFilter: 'info' }}
</div>
```

This code will send `"1"` to the filter and get the text `"John"`

After that I want the controller to change it like this:

```js
if (condition==true){    
    SugNechesRcsFilter.Replace("John","John Doe");
}
```

Comment: I can see every single answer on your questions has not gotten your upvote or approval. This makes questions like this one pop up at the homepage of Stackoverflow because the idea is that there is no answer yet. Could you accept (all other questions you have answers for too) if the answer is useful please? This also motivates others to write answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is `SugNechesRcsFilter` your own code? Then add the condition there with a `map` function.

Otherwise you would have to write your own filter and pipe it once more:

`{{ vm.currSugNeches | SugNechesRcsFilter: 'info' | yourOwnFilter }}`

That filter does not live inside your controller, but as a separate component.

A howto on filters:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

*the following snippet is not tested, but an example*

```js
angular.
  module('core').
  filter('yourOwnFilter', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return input.map(item => item === '1' ? 'John' : item;
    };
  });
```